# HTML Validation Issues - form validation firing on button click

Tags: html, validation

I have HTML validation across my web site, but I am facing some issue with that.

I have one form and for the validation I have used HTML validation:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" ToolTip="Plz, Enter Valid First Name" placeholder="Contact first name" pattern="[A-z ]*" required="required"> </asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnsubmit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

On button click it will fire.

The problem is that I have also used one form popup on the same page. And I  have validation on the popup as well. So when I click the button on popup, the page validation is firing.

Does HTML have any group validation, like ASP.NET validation has? If no then is there any other way so I can avoid firing validation on the page on click of popup button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the HTML validation and create new, custom validation using JavaScript.